# Is there have way to add more than 10 phonenumbers in a contact on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a StoredContact with more than 10 phonenumbers, but I found this API doesn't have too much properties allow me do that, is there any other methods can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference my last post at here:[Can I link multiple contacts to one by programming on WP8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351011/can-i-link-multiple-contacts-to-one-by-programming-on-wp8-1)

Then you can create a linked contacts which it can have as many phonenumber as you want.