# Can I link multiple contacts to one by programming on WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In People Hub, user can link multiple contacts to one. Here I want to ask if there is a way or API to made it by programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way, that is you can create some contacts with the same name and the same phonenumbers, the People Hub will link them together automatically. It may need a few time, after that, you can change their any information freely.